# Submit form with second submit button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having two submit button on a form named 'Save' and 'Delete'. Now I want to explicitly do submit with Delete button. How can I do it? 
I have tried following:

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

and

```
$('#myForm').bind('Delete').submit(); // Delete is value of delete submit button.
```

but it don't work for delete functionality. Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$('delete selector').bind('click', function() { $('#myForm').submit() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use jQuery? Can you not make the delete button a submit type?

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"/>
```

Or:

```
<button type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
```

Comment: @DH__ then something is wrong with your HTML, show the form code in your question.